# SSIS Package Deployment -DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008, ssis, dts

[image]> [OLE DB Source [113]] Error: SSIS Error Code

> DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "msAccess"
>   failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method
>   call failed. .

I am new in  SSIS Packages designing for learning purpose I am Designing dtsx packages. i have a .mdb file that I am trying to import in my sql server 2016 . when I design packages it running successfully  but when I deploy that packages and try to run that packages through package utility it showing me above error.
i searched a lot i changed my packages properties like delay validation= true and validate external metadata = false.
But after deploying packages data is not loading into my respective table.

Comment: Add a screenshot of the connection manager for the .mdb file.

Comment: as u said i added screenshot of my .mdb file connection string. please see that

Comment: **Data Source=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\msAccess.mdb;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;**             This is the connection Path for my mdb file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for late reply. I gave SQL server agent permission access to my packages and they are running through my stored procedure and also my mdb file i gave access to SQL server agent to access that file –

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that you don't have the .mdb file in the same local folder on the SQL Server:

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\msAccess.mdb

When you deploy the package and run it through the package utility, the package is running ON the SQL Server, and not on your local box anymore.  So any local path in the package will be interpreted as a local path on the SQL Server.

Comment: as u said , so I need to change the path of my mdb file? where should i locate my mdb file

Comment: You need to locate the file on your SQL Server, or on a share that your SQL Server has access to.   What I do is create a simple path like C:\SSIS\ and put that path on my local box and on all my SSIS Servers, and use that as the root for my files that need to be accessed by SSIS.

Comment: I created ** C:\SSIS\ ** and kept my mdb file in that path but i didn't get  the point as u saying  " put path on local box and SSIS Server" .   I changed path in my config file and again run that packages but still same

Comment: in a C drive i created SSIS folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165501/discussion-between-tej-and-tab-alleman).

Comment: I saved that file in c drive of my server

Comment: If you put the .mdb file in a folder on your SSIS SQL Server, and then put that file path in the .config file that is also on the same SQL Server, and the user running the utility has permission to read that folder, then your package should work.   If it doesn't work, then one of those steps was not done correctly.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I gave SQL server agent permission access to my packages and they are running through my stored procedure and also my mdb file i gave access to SQL server agent to access that file

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adjusting which elements of my connection managers are parameterized.

I learned that you should parameterize either the entire connection string or the individual elements of the connection string. Not both.

As soon as I removed the ConnectionString parameter it worked fine. I just have the Password and DataSource parameterized. I used to have those plus the ConnectionString parameterized. But it is not necessary and just trips up SSIS. Only parameterize what you absolutely need to.